# How to authenticate users using rubycas-server in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise, rubycas-server

I'm using `rubycas-server` GEM as my CAS server. This CAS server is checking user credentials from a user table of a different database. These users are created using `Devise` gem. Devise saves every user's password in encrypted form in database table. So in the configuration file of this `rubycas-server` contains a `authenticator` section, It's code is given below:

```
authenticator:
 class: CASServer::Authenticators::SQL
 database:
   adapter: postgresql
   database: testdb
   username: postgres
   password: root
   host: localhost
   pool: 5
 user_table: users
 username_column: email
 password_column: encrypted_password
 encrypt_function: <encryption function>
```

As stated above in the last line of code that, `encrypted_function` contains the algorithm to check credentials. Some samples given gelow in the URL

https://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/wiki/UsingTheSQLEncryptedAuthenticator

But I can't find what will be suitable for `devise`. Please help.

Comment: I think rubycas-server supports Bcrypt by default and Devise using Bcrypt. so could you please remove that line and see what happens.

Comment: If I remove that line then `rubycas-server` is by default checking normal string password. Means the password entered in the login form is checked directly with the encrypted password, then every time it's showing "Incorrect login credentials"

Comment: Are you sure about the credentials(Username and password) you are entering is same as which have already stored in the authenticator db ie testdb.

Comment: yes, the credentials are correct, and the `rubycas-server` is not encrypting the login form password by default, because when I'm giving the encrypted_password string from database in login form then it's authenticating.

Comment: @ManojMenon I found the SQLBcrypt in `rubycas-server`, do you know to to configure this `SQLBcrypt` authenticator?

Comment: no,actually i had tried to use Ruby cas-server it was working fine without encrypt_function. You can also try Casino http://casino.rbcas.com/ which is well documented and great.

Comment: @ManojMenon thanks for your advise, but I got my solution

Comment: How, could you put it as a comment, it may help others also for future reference!

Comment: @ManojMenon, Wait I will give my answer after I fully test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got solution for my question. Actually the `encrypt_function:` not needed in authenticator settings. As I'm using email and encrypted_password which is generated by `Devise` to check a user's credentials, the final authenticator is:

```
authenticator:
  class: CASServer::Authenticators::SQLBcrypt
  database:
   adapter: postgresql
   database: testdb
   username: postgres
   password: root
   host: localhost
   pool: 5
  user_table: users
  username_column: email
  password_column: encrypted_password
```

As Devise user `BCrypt` by default to encrypt the password, That's why I'm using `CASServer::Authenticators::SQLBcrypt` class. But `rubycas-server` gem don't set `SQLBcrypt` configurations by default. So go to `lib/casserver/authenticators/authlogic_crypto_providers` path and open `brypt.rb` file. In this file you can see these lines are commented, so un-comment them or if not present then add them

```
    acts_as_authentic do |c|
     c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::BCrypt
    end
```

Then run `gem install bcrypt-ruby` in your terminal or add this GEM to `rubycas-server` GEMFILE and restart the server. I think this should work.